# how to install android studio 0.8.14

Tags: android

I am trying to install android studio 0.8.14 from this page.

I download the zip file and unzip it into a directory and the run studio.exe ( as explained in documentation on web site)

but when I run studio.exe, I found that android sdk was not installed.

what is the correct procedures to install android studio on windows?

Comment: Just download from here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: @m0skit0 I followed the steps on that page, but it was not installed. No SDK was installed!

Comment: Just trying it, works fine. When you start Android Studio and start creating your first project, it automatically downloads the SDK.

Comment: @m0skit0 mine doesn't do that :( it say sdk is not available and doesn't allow me to create a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i, and look to the section called "GET THE SDK FOR AN EXISTING IDE", download that to a known location and then use that folder when android studio asks you to point to sdk location

Comment: did that, but android studio doesn't ask me about where is sdk .

Comment: @mans go to File-> Project Structure -> SDK Location and set it there

Answer (score 0):

Download the SDK from [here](http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe).
This link can be found on [Android SDK | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

after downloading the sdk , open studio64.exe ->configure->project default->project structure-> set android SDK location to that of standalone sdk installation directory [by default its "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"].

note- start sdk manager as administrator. else it wont do anything